# Powershell Task Scheduler 0x1

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

This task completes but I get the 0x1 error.  I have run Set the execution policy to Bypass have the privs set as pictured below.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does task scheduler have permissions to your folder?  Try testing by moving the script to c:\temp

Comment: I think so since I had it here before:  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Custom and it still did not work.

Comment: I would try creating a C:\temp and permission that folder then move the file to that location to avoid restrictive permissions from affecting you

Comment: did you check the event viewer? anything logged there?

Comment: Same error after moving to c:\temp

Comment: Where are you setting the execution policy to bypass?  Is it as part of your argument line as we cannot see the end

Answer (score 0):

Choice "Run whether user is logged or not"
Save. You must give the password.

This avoid right problems for me (user is admin, of course).

Ok, strange but works for me.